# Makefile Executable Error

Tags: c, makefile

I have the following Makefile:

```
all: test.c test1.c
    gcc -o test test.c -lm
    gcc -o test1 test1.c
    ./test 1000 input.txt
```

I am getting an error like `./test 1000 input.txt make: *** [run] Error 255`. Is the Makefile correct?

Comment: Error 255 is something in the line of "command not found". It might be the path (but you already added `./`) or the compilation failed and there is no  executable (but that would have caused GCC to throw the towel with a more or less useful comment). So please check if everything is build and at its proper. Is this the only error?

Comment: Yes this is the only error.

Comment: @deamentiaemundi I have updated my question above to make it simpler. Can you take a look again?

Comment: _Is this the correct way to do it?_ To do what?

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov Like running the executable test inside of the `all` part of the make file? Basically this part: `./test 1000 input.txt` I am getting the error there.

Comment: @1290 I was not able to recreate your error with two example files (just printing given arguments) and your makefile, all in one directory. Please add `-W -Wall -Wextra -pedantic` directly after `gcc`, I have some suspicions.

Comment: Directly after both of the gcc's?

Comment: Are you returning -1 from `main` in your C file? Or forgetting to return anything?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart THANK you so much!!!! I forgot to `return 0` in main file. You just saved me another 50 edits to my makefile... Maybe you can put that as an answer I can accept it so others can see it as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
./test 1000 input.txt make: *** [run] Error 255
```

This doesn't mean anything is wrong with your Makefile. It means that your `./test` program ran an exited with status 255.

You haven't showed us `test.c`, but I'm assuming you didn't write `return 255;`. Since the exit status is usually only 8 bits, it's possible you (incorrectly) wrote `return -1`. It's also possible that you (incorrectly) omitted a return statement from `main` which leads to Undefined Behavior, and -1 happens to be in the return value register  (`eax` on x86).

---

You should *always* enable compiler warnings. To force you to correct them, these warnings (which often indicate broken code) should cause the compilation to fail as well.

```
CFLAGS = -Wall -Wextra -Werror

test: test.c
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^
```

Comment: This was the error! I forgot to `return 0;` in my main method in test.c. Thank you!